# Moxiemanager plugin error at the upload

Tags: tinymce

Moxiemanager plugin error at the upload.

I integrated MoxieManager into my TinyMCE, when I click on the Image icon, I click the the camera icon to get the upload dialog box up, then I insert one file, click upload. This is where I got the error.

I have .net Framework 4.5 installed.

The dome page from the MoxieManager download doesn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated!